# Is there a way to Include the Footer and header or other default sections of web page when I created file?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, web-deployment

To be clear I am not asking include() or require() in PHP, I'm asking

when I create file using fopen() and fwrite() in other file, I can insert text content with right? but now I want to insert the Footer and header & other default sections of that web page with it when I create it.
So how can I achieve that without fetching the content from database?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you must create your file as a view, lets name it **myfile_template**

and its code should go like this

#### View File

```
@include('header')
<p>your file content i'il show you how to pass data to it </p>
@include('footer')
```

#### In Controller

then in your controller you wanna convert that view into a string and then save it in a file

```
$user = User::All();
$mycontent= view('myfile_template', compact('user'))->render();
```